# Responsive design/@media design breakdown not functioning as should

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am very new to Responsive/Adaptive design and am having a bit of trouble with my media queries for the mobile versions. I have built a couple of sites before with the same queries, and have not run into this problem. The result I am looking for displays fine in Mozilla Firefox (at smallest breakdown/resize to 480px) but not anywhere else, (most importantly on mobile phones).

I have the site temporarily live for testing at http://adapdivdesign.com/scff/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: I apologize for the quick post without specifying the problem. My main concern is the sites' main navigation is supposed to change and breakdown to the mobile version (as seen in Mozilla Firefox). From the "sign post" to the horizontal bar look.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't close the 767 media query properly?

```
/* ============================= */
/* ! 767 767 767 767 767 767 767 */
/* ============================= */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
```

The 480 media query is contained in the 767 media query.

Comment: WOW! what a rookie mistake on my end thank you thank you @Lokase. Problem solved and removing my test site for privacy purposes.

Comment: no worries Peter.  I tend to organize my media query code to take into account those extra braces to avoid these kinds of mix ups.  Please up vote the answer if it was correct. Thanks!